# Rails has_many association methods missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I recently started learning rails and going through a tutorial using has_many associations but I'm running into all manners of missing method errors.

I have the following models

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

According to [Active Record Associations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

> When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class automatically gains 17 methods related to the association

So I should be able to get member data when I use Team.members but I get the following error:

```
irb(main):004:0> Team.members
/home/jia/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord- 
7.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `members' 
for Team:Class (NoMethodError)                                                         
irb(main):005:0> 

irb(main):011:0> Team.size
/home/jia/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord- 
7.0.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `size' 
for Team:Class (NoMethodError)                                                            
irb(main):012:0>
```

Upon checking Team.methods I don't see the 17 association methods. What am I missing or doing wrong?

I'm using Rails 7.0.1 and ruby 3.0.3

For now I'm using includes to connect the two tables but I would like to be able to use the association methods.

Comment: Those methods are available on instance of Team and not on class. you can access it like `Team.last.comments`, `Team.last.comments.size`

Comment: I royally missed that part. Thank you very much. You should maybe put it as answer so I could accept.

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate as its a super common beginner hangup. I just can't figure out a good search term.